# Why do probablity distribution with orthogonal suppor have maximal Kolmogorov distance?

Tags: information-theory, trace-distance, probability

Can anyone explain why the $l_1$ distance has the property that probability distributions $P,Q$ with orthogonal support (meaning that the product $p_iq_i$ vanishes for each value of $i$) are at a maximal distance from each other?
Consider $$ \|P-Q\|_1=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|p_i-q_i|$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $p_{i}q_{i} = 0\,\,\forall i$, then for all $i$ either $p_{i} = 0$, $q_{i} = 0$, or both are $0$.

Divide $\{i\} = \{1,\ldots,N\}$  into those $i$ for which these three different things happen: $\{N_{p_{i}}\} = \{i|p_{i} = 0\}$, $\{N_{q_{i}}\} = \{i|q_{i} = 0\}$, $\{N_{pq_{i}}\} = \{i|p_{i} = q_{i} = 0\}$.

Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|P-Q\|_{1} =& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|p_{i}-q_{i}| \\ 
=& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in N_{p_{i}}}|p_{i}-q_{i}| + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in N_{q_{i}}}|p_{i}-q_{i}| + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in N_{pq_{i}}}|p_{i}-q_{i}| \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in N_{p_{i}}}|q_{i}| + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in N_{q_{i}}}|p_{i}| + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in N_{pq_{i}}}|0| \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\Big(\sum_{i \in \{N\}}q_{i} + \sum_{i \in \{N\}} p_{i}\Big) = 1,
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where the last line follows from the fact that
$$
1 = \sum_{i\in \{N\}}|q_{i}| = \sum_{i\in N_{p_{i}}}|q_{i}| + \sum_{i\in N_{q_{i}}}|q_{i}| + \sum_{i\in N_{pq_{i}}}|q_{i}| = \sum_{i\in N_{p_{i}}}|q_{i}| + 0 + 0 = \sum_{i\in N_{p_{i}}}|q_{i}|,
$$
and likewise for $\sum_{i}p_{i}$. That is, we can add these other terms of $q_{i}$ ($p_{i}$) because they are $0$ by construction anyway.

This is the maximum value that $\|P-Q\|_{1}$ can take for *any* $P$ and $Q$, because $|p_{i} - q_{i}| \leq |p_{i}| + |-q_{i}| = p_{i} + q_{i}$ for any $p_{i},q_{i}$ imaginable, and as such:

$$
\|P-Q\|_{1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|p_{i}-q_{i}| \leq \frac{1}{2}\big(\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_{i}+q_{i}\big) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_{i} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}q_{i} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} = 1
$$

Comment: can you please explain why the maximum value of $\|P-Q\|_1$ is 1?

Comment: Can I use minkowski inequality to show the maximum value equals to 1?

Comment: You can use the triangle inequality on each of the terms in the sum to show that it is bounded above by $1$.

Comment: @Rammus thanks! I was just adding it to my answer too:)

Comment: @Sakh10 Please see the added text